# Evaluating indefinite integral $\int \frac{3x}{x-2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{3x}{x-2}\,dx$$

The answer is $3(2\ln|x-2|+x)+C\,$, but I don't understand how this is the answer. I thought I could just separate the $x$ on the numerator from the equation and evaluate them separately to  get
 $$\frac{3x^2\ln\left|x-2\right|}{2}$$ 
as the answer. Why doesn't my approach work?

Comment: $\int f(x) g(x)\, dx \neq \int f(x) \, dx \int g(x) \, dx.$  take the units of $f, g$ to be miles per hour and the unit of $x$ to be hour. the left hand side has the unit $\frac{mile^2}{hour}$ and the right has the unit $mile^2.$ i. e. even the units won't agree, let alone both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: try writing the numerator instead as $3x-6+6$ and break it into two nice terms.

Alternatively, try a change of variable $u = x-2$.

Comment: You beat me by seconds.

Comment: @Sumo, you beat me by seconds too.

Comment: @Sumo: you beat me by 13 minutes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still confused. How will that first part help? I got the same answer with the exception of -2x and 2x in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The integral of a product is *not* the product of the integrals:
$$\begin{align}
\int 3x \;dx &= \frac{3x^2}{2} + C\\
\int \frac{1}{x-2}dx &= \ln|x-2| + C\\
\int \frac{3x}{x-2} \;dx &\neq \frac{3x^2\ln|x-2|}{2} + C
\end{align}$$
Try to do something like this instead:
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{3x}{x-2} \;dx &= \int \left(3 + \frac{6}{x-2}\right) \;dx\\
 &= \int 3\;dx + \int \frac{6}{x-2} \;dx\\
 &= 3x + 6\ln|x-2| + C
\end{align}$$

Comment: Where did the x in the numerator go in the first part?

Comment: $\dfrac{3x}{x-2} = \dfrac{3(x-2)+6}{x-2} = \dfrac{3(x-2)}{x-2}+\dfrac{6}{x-2} = 3+\dfrac{6}{x-2}$

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose another method, for the education of the OP. By using long division and doing the following operation, you end up with a simplified answer.

$$\require{enclose}x\enclose{longdiv}{x-2}$$

You end up with $1+\dfrac{2}{x-2}$ which is very easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Write it as

$$3\int\frac{x}{x-2}dx = 3\int\frac{x-2+2}{x-2}dx = 3\int 1 + \frac{2}{x-2} dx =3[ x + 2\ln(x + 2)] + C =\dots$$

This gives the final answer

Comment: Please do not place dollar signs around each symbol separately. Instead, place the entire equation between dollar signs (or double dollar signs if you want it displayed as I have done).

Comment: Thanks for the help @MichaelAlbanese. I am quite new to Mathjax, so this is a bit chines for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively, try a $u$-substitution. Let $u = x-2$, then $dx = du$ and $x = u + 2$, so your integral becomes

$$3\int \dfrac{u+2}{u} du = 3\int \left(1 + \frac{2}{u}\right)du =\quad ...$$

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer

$\int\frac{3x}{x-2}dx$

$=\int\frac{3(x-2)+6}{x-2}dx$

$=3\int dx+6\int\frac{1}{x-2}dx$

$=3x+6\ln(x-2)+c$

c is cosntant of integration